# Loop that terminates when condition is met

Tags: python

I was doing some python practice and have been stumped with this question. I have figured out how to do all the operations but do not know how to create the terminating loop, any help would be appreciated.

Question:
Write a program that generates 2 numbers between 1 and 15.  Display them in order from biggest to smallest. Display the sum of the numbers. The program should continue until the random numbers generated are the same.  At the end of the program display, the total sum of all the numbers generated.

```py
from random import randint

numberOne = randint(1, 15)
numberTwo = randint(1, 15)

print("Your two random numbers are: ", numberOne, numberTwo)
print()

if (numberOne > numberTwo):
    biggest_num = numberOne
elif (numberTwo > numberOne):
    biggest_num = numberTwo

if (numberOne < numberTwo):
    smallest_num = numberOne
elif (numberTwo < numberOne):
    smallest_num = numberTwo

print("From biggest to smallest, the two random numbers are: ", biggest_num, smallest_num)
print("The sum of the two numbers is: ", numberOne + numberTwo)
```

Comment: I this problem from HackerRank or some other site? You just need a while loop that will run until number generated is repeated and you need an array to store them.

Comment: -1, try minimal research. Any search for words like "python terminating loop".  You will find pages upon pages explaining the `break` statement.

Comment: @Cireo You may be right but don't be so harsh on him, no need for that. He's probably a beginner, just like me. I'm sure he'll use already existing information if his knowledge increases in the future. But for a beginner it can be very helpful if someone improves the code directly instead of having to try all sorts of stuff you don't understand yet as a new kid.

Comment: @Cireo I apologize for asking a silly question lol. I recognized that a terminating loop was needed, I just didn't know how to implement it in the code as I am still learning, the resources online were hard to follow

Comment: Nothing against you or your question, it just isn't the right spot for it at all.  If you want some help looking at your code, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  Someone feeding you a revised version of your code here doesn't help the next viewer, because the generic version of your question is "how do you terminate a loop?"

Comment: @Cireo when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". The OP asked a question there but it was off-topic, likely because of unfamiliarity with the site.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the meta-comment =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest approach here is an infinite loop with a `break`

```py
from random import randint

total_sum = 0

while True:
    numberOne = randint(1, 15)
    numberTwo = randint(1, 15)

    print("Your two random numbers are: ", numberOne, numberTwo)
    print()

    if numberOne == numberTwo:
        break

    if numberOne > numberTwo:
        biggest_num = numberOne
    elif numberTwo > numberOne:
        biggest_num = numberTwo

    if numberOne < numberTwo:
        smallest_num = numberOne
    elif numberTwo < numberOne:
        smallest_num = numberTwo

    print("From biggest to smallest, the two random numbers are: ", biggest_num, smallest_num)
    print("The sum of the two numbers is: ", numberOne + numberTwo)
    total_sum += numberOne + numberTwo

print('Total sum:', total_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
import random
numberOne = 0
numberTwo = 1


while numberOne != numberTwo:
    numberOne = random.randint(1, 15)
    numberTwo = random.randint(1, 15)

    print('\nYour two numbers are:', numberOne, numberTwo)

    if numberOne > numberTwo:
        largest = numberOne
        smallest = numberTwo
    else:
        largest = numberTwo
        smallest = numberOne

    print('From largest to smallest, the two random numbers are:', largest, smallest)
    print('The sum of the two numbers is:', numberOne + numberTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

numbers = set()
while(True):
    numberOne = random.randint(1, 15)
    numberTwo = random.randint(1, 15)
    numbers.update([numberOne,numberTwo])
    if (numberOne==numberTwo):
        break
    print("From biggest to smallest, the two random numbers are: ",sorted([numberOne,numberTwo],reverse=True))
    print("The sum of the two numbers is: ",sum([numberOne,numberTwo]))
print('--------------------------------------------------------------')
print("From biggest to smallest, all random numbers are: ",sorted(list(numbers),reverse=True))
print("The sum of all numbers is: ",sum(numbers))
```